# ? instead of value with zend update

Tags: php, zend-framework, insert-update

I'm trying to make updates querys with Zend_Db_Adapter but when I make an echo of the querys, the value that I want to update is still an "?". I check the value $foo, I always have 1 or 0
My code :

```
$this->_db->beginTransaction();
try {
    foreach($a_result as $k => $j){
        $foo = ($j['val1'] >= $j['val2']) ? 1 : 0 ;
        $a_data = array('bar' => $foo);
        $where['id = ?'] = $k;
        $update = $this->_db->update($this->_name, $a_data, $where);                                    
    }
    $this->_db->commit();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->_db->rollBack();
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

All my querys looks like this :

- UPDATE `foo` SET `bar` = ? WHERE (id = 39)
- UPDATE `foo` SET `bar` = ? WHERE (id = 40)
- [...]

Comment: check if its considering the value of $foo as boolean, May be you need to cast the value of $foo

Comment: Its considering $foo as an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works for me, try to put it inside your loop and see if it helps :)

```
$a_data = array(
            'bar' => $foo
);

$_where = array();
$_where[] = "id = '" . $k . "'";
```

Besides that, I think your problem resides in the $where, it's written in a strange way. I usually use, for selects

```
->where('ID = ? ', $k)
```

In your case I would use

```
$where = $this->_yourTable->getAdapter()->quoteInto('id = ?', $id)
```

Anyway, the first one should be simpler!

Comment: It work better with this syntax, thanks. By the way the synthax I use above is the one show in Zend 1.x documentation.

Comment: I'm using Zend 1.12 too, but, honestly I never tried your syntax, since this one worked. I can't exclude there's a better way though, but I'm glad this helped you :)